# delete.edges doesn't work in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I want to delete all edges that link to node '1' but the function delete.edges doesn't work:

```
g<-graph.full(n=10, directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE)
g <- delete.edges(g,c(2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1))
plot(g)
```

When viewing the graph, nothing changes! what is the problem ?

Comment: Try `as_edgelist(g)`: you'll see the list of edges of the graph. Then, you have to pass the row indices of the link you want to remove. For instance `g<-delete.edges(g,which(as_edgelist(g)==1,arr.ind=TRUE)[,1])` removes any edge starting from or arriving to 1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works well. But how to remove scattered or listed edges? such as the following edges. : (2,4), (5,1),(9,3),(7,4),(10,6)

Comment: Try this: `delete.edges(g,c("2|4","5|1","9|3"))` for instance.

Comment: Thank you again. And how to remove a set of vertices?
I tried with: g<-delete.vertices(g,c(2,4,5))
But the vertices are not removed!

Answer (score 0):

To delete  (2,4), (5,1),(9,3),(7,4),(10,6) use:

```
delete_edges(g, get.edge.ids(g, c(2,4, 5,1, 9,3, 7,4, 10,6)))
```