# delete.edges is not workiong in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am working on the Stanford igraph tutorials and am getting the following error in the 6th tutorial (https://sna.stanford.edu/lab.php?l=6) for line number 53 in that tutorial. That line reads

```
m182_friend <- delete.edges(m182_full, E(m182_full)[E(m182_full)$friend_tie==0])
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Error in delete.edges(m182_full, E(m182_full)[E(m182_full)$friend_tie ==  : 
  delete.edges requires an argument of class network.
```

Both arguments to the delete.edges() function run successfully.

```
> class(E(m182_full)[E(m182_full)$social_tie==0])<p>
[1] "igraph.es"<p>
> class(m182_full)<p>
[1] "igraph"<p>
```

Clearly the second argument returns an edge sequence (.es) instead of a network. The other posting related to this type of problem ([delete.edges doesn't work in igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040517/delete-edges-doesnt-work-in-igraph)) did not address my particular issue.

Thanks for your help

Comment: not reproducible, have you installed all the packages?

Comment: try `delete_edges`

Comment: Am using R version library(igraph)
library(sna)
library(triads)
library(psych)
library(nFactors)
library(NetCluster)

Comment: Thanks a ton.delete_edges worked! How in the world, why in the world would I have known that ? :))

Comment: @Raj sna also has `delete.edges`, and you were calling that instead of the `igraph` one....

Comment: Thanks Gabor ... I was using one of the tutorials from the Stanford site (https://sna.stanford.edu/lab.php?l=6). So now I am not sure whether the code ran propitiously and I just lucked out. There must be a way to disambiguate the calls because that code loads both "sna" as well as "igraph" packages at startup - see my prior email.

Comment: There's a fair amount of overlap between `igraph` and `sna`/`network`. I try not to have them both loaded at the same time. In cases where I know there is overlap and I have both loaded, I add `igraph::` to the call.

Comment: @paqmo Thanks for your suggestion. That, I believe, is the way to go when both packages are loaded